# socket recv Consuming CPU

Tags: c++, ace

One of our product user is claiming that in our product `socket recv` is consuming very high CPU. We are using `ACE`.  I tried locally but could not reproduce the issue. I am looking for probable reasons why would `socket recv` would consume high `CPU`.

Comment: Perhaps they have a small MTU (1500 bytes usually) this might increase the overhead when obtaining a big load of data. perhaps your network card can mimick smal values and then you can check your cpuload. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

Comment: Check if your code isn't using `recv` with a very small data buffer, for example (extreme) 4 bytes instead of ~1kB.

Comment: It may mean just that the application is spending a lot of time *blocked* in recv(), which is normal.